# Cear output from rest api with jq

Tags: rest, jq

I am wanting to be able to use rest API and am discouraged about the barely readable json output. Can jq format json into a simpler more clear data. If JQ does not do this does anyone know of a tool that would Make Rest API more readable to humans?

Comment: Have you tried just calling `jq . your.json`? It should give you a colored and pretty-printed output.

Comment: M.R.P. - Please correct the title. It's unclear what you mean by "Cear".

Answer (score 0):

There are many tools that will allow you to "pretty-print" JSON to make it easier to read.  In the case of jq, simply presenting the JSON to `jq .` (e.g. `curl ... | jq .`) will pretty-print it, unless it is ridiculously large (i.e., too large to fit into the computer's memory), in which case you probably won't want to pretty-print it anyway.

If the issue is that even pretty-printing the JSON is insufficient to make it comprehensible, then you might find a simple "schema inference engine" appropriate.  The one I wrote at https://gist.github.com/pkoppstein/a5abb4ebef3b0f72a6ed (schema.jq) produces an easy-to-understand structural schema.  Examples, including examples of how to invoke it, are available at https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/X---Experimental-Benchmarks

The simplest way to use it with curl would be to download it as schema.jq, uncomment the very last line, and then invoke it along the following lines:

```
curl .... | jq -f schema.jq
```

E.g.:

```
curl -Ss https://gitlab.cern.ch/slac_sandbox/ubjson/-/raw/504d419d3e6a4ab87488fcc750bb79c6f5471491/benchmarks/files/jeopardy/jeopardy.json |
  jq --arg nullable true -f schema.jq
{
  "air_date": "string",
  "answer": "string",
  "category": "string",
  "question": "string",
  "round": "string",
  "show_number": "string",
  "value": "string"
}
```